# Javascript slideshow using timers

Tags: javascript, html, timer, slideshow, src

I'm apparently a bit of a dunce. I've been trying to get this to work as an onload slideshow that will randomly cycle through some images. I've looked through four different questions on here pertaining to how to change the src attribute using javascript and I *think* that I've avoided all of the problems that have been mentioned on those. The HTML calls the slideShow() function, but for the life of me I can't actually get the src to change and display on the page. Can someone please help me figure out what I've done wrong?

```
<script><!--

function slideShow()
{
    window.setInterval("changeImage()", 5000);
}

function changeImage()
{   
var imgSrcs["images//traps//1.jpg",
    "images//traps//2.jpg",
    "images//traps//3.jpg",
    "images//traps//4.jpg"]
var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
var element = document.getElementById("slideShow").src;
element.innerHTML.src= imgSrcs[i];
}
--></script>
```

The HTML element that goes with this is:

```
    <p><img src = "images//traps//1.jpg" alt = "Traps available for use" id = "slideShow"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the following lines

```
var element = document.getElementById("slideShow").src;
element.innerHTML.src= imgSrcs[i];
```

with

```
var element = document.getElementById("slideShow");
element.src= imgSrcs[i];
```

I've assumed that slideShow refers to img tag id.

Comment: It does refer to the img tag ID, but even with your updates, it still won't run.

Comment: Ah. There was a mistake in my declaration of the array. Working now. :)